# WIX-based installation results in an invalid configuration file

Tags: web-config, wix, wix3.5

**EDIT**

I've decided to try to find a simpler way to ask this question:

If my WIX-based installation needs to modify an XML file that looks like this:

```
<a>
  <b/>
</a>
```

into one that looks like this:

```
<a>
  <c/>
  <b/>
<a/>
```

Can it be done *without* a custom action?

Using the XmlConfig element, the closest I can get is this:

```
<a>
  <b/>
  <c/>
<a/>
```

The problem, if I have not made it plain, is that the inserted `c` element must come before the `b` element already in the file.

Comment: I think there may be a problem with your xpath.  What do your xpaths look like within your XmlConfig elements?

Comment: You are referring to the ElementPath attribute of the XmlConfig element, yes? Per the documentation, this specifies '...the parent element being modified...'. As such it is behaving exactly as I would expect: the new elements are created as direct children of the parent element specified. The problem is that the parent element already has child content and at least one of the new elements must be inserted before that content, not after (as is the case presently).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XmlConfig and XmlFile get converted to custom actions btw.  Can you start with a different xml file such that you can add all children nodes to the parent in the correct sequence?  Otherwise, you can request this behavior as a new feature request to the WiX team here: http://sourceforge.net/tracker/?group_id=105970&atid=642717

Comment: Yes, I am aware that XmlConfig is technically a custom action. I meant that I would rather avoid a 'custom' custom action in favor of relying on the built-in features of WIX.

Comment: The real XML file in question is actually that of another software package (Microsoft SQL Server Reporting Services), so no I cannot practically start with a different XML file.

Comment: This is not supported as a built-in feature of WiX.  As previously suggested, create a new feature request for the WiX team.  Also, you can request the feature to other third party wix extension libraries like http://msiext.codeplex.com.  XmlConfig uses the IXMLDOMNode::appendChild method where it seems you would need to use the IXMLDOMNode::insertBefore method for example.

Comment: Well, it may not be the answer that I wanted, but 'it can't be done' is still an answer, so I've accepted.